# Java Database - each record has a file

Tags: java, database

Imagine a database where there's one main table with several columns - mostly of simple types (text/string, int, etc.). There is one column for a textual blob in the table.

I'm looking for a database that will store the table in one file and then store each blob in a file of its own on the hard drive. We're looking for 100,000 or so records in the database.

The database needs to be embedable and run on Java 6.

Searching online brought me to things like Derby and managing the storage of the blob files myself (references to paths). I was hoping there was a better solution.

Comment: Why do you care about that?

Comment: I want to easily edit the different files using tools like vi before the files are deployed to the production location. The database is generated in the development environment.